# Source not found for internal java classes in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, internals

I use eclipse and lots of times I need to open a source file of an internal class in java. I do this by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>click</kbd> on that object. For example I want to see the codes of the `Scanner` class, and when I try to open it by <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>click</kbd> on a `Scanner` object, it shows that, "source is not found". The error is this:

> The JAR file in /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar has no source attachment.
>
> You can attach the source by clicking Attach Source below:

And there is an <kbd>Attach Source</kbd> button under it. I searched a lot but all people had the same problem with the projects on their filesystem, not the internal classes. What should I do? Is there a way to change that `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar` file?

Comment: Use a JDK rather than just the JRE. The JDK contains source and Eclipse will find it.

Comment: @greg-449 I don't know how to change it. I've installed `openjdk-8-jre` package. What should I install?

Comment: Probably 'openjdk-8-jdk'

Comment: @greg-449 I had to install `openjdk-8-source`. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do

```
$ sudo apt install openjdk-8-source
$ sudo updatedb
$ mlocate src.zip
```

Copy the last command's location. It usually is `/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-8/src.zip`.

Then, click <kbd>Attach Source...</kbd>, and click on <kbd>External location</kbd>. Then paste that command's output in the text field. (You can open the file by clicking on <kbd>External File...</kbd> and finding that `src.zip` file in your filesystem.)